# ODE Solution not plotting

Tags: graphics

Why is the following code not plotting?

DSolve[y''[t] + 0.05 y'[t] + 25 y[t] == (4/Pi) Cos[t], y[t], t];
Plot[y[t], {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions"]

Comment: Work for me:`sol = DSolve[y''[t] + 5/100*y'[t] + 25*y[t] == (4/Pi)*Cos[t], y[t], 
  t]; Plot[y[t] /. sol /. C[1] -> 1 /. C[2] -> 1, {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotLabels -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: Plotting `DSolve` solutions is show in the docs for `DSolve` under Scope > Basic Uses. Of course, one can plot only particular solutions, not the general solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with what you have. The first is that without specific boundary/initial conditions you are only going to get a general solution to your ODE. If you look at the output from the call to `DSolve` you will see two undetermined constants, `C[1]` and `C[2]`. The second relates to how the solution is passed to the `Plot` function. Mathematica does not automatically store the solution to the ODE in `DSolve`. You either have to assign the solution to a variable or directly reference the solution in `Plot`. There is ample information on the proper use of `DSolve` in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html.en).

Here is a possible solution to your problem:

```
sol = DSolve[{y''[t] + 1/20 y'[t] + 25 y[t] == (4/Pi) Cos[t], 
    y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}, y[t], t];
Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]